# How to keep the top N docs by query and remove all other in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find an optimal way to remove all docs except top N returned by a find query.

What we are currently doing is to get all the doc ids sorting and skipping N. Then firing remove with a query as `{id: {$in: idsList}}`.

```
1. model.find(findQuery).sort({_id:-1}).skip(N) -> collecting all ids from this query(idsList)

2. model.remove({_id:{'$in':idsList}})
```

Is there any way to do this in an optimal way using single query?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing opposite of it.

```
1. idsList = model.find(findQuery).sort({_id:-1}).limit(N)


2. model.remove({_id:{'$nin':idsList}})
```

Comment: We can't say this will be best always, can we? If N is higher(than it would've been skipped), the other way would have been best.